# Is there any way to print yesterday date in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to use yesterday's date in one of my jenkins pipeline.

Is there any way to print yesterday date in jenkins pipeline script.

```
def date = new date()
println date // this is printing the current date 

def date1 = date - 1 or date.minus(1)
println date 1 // This is also printing the current date.
```

Is there any way to get yesterday date in jenkins pipeline script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This'll work.

```
def today = new Date()
def yesterday = today - 1
println today.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
println yesterday.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Output:

```
03/25/2020 -- Today's date
03/24/2020 -- Yesterday's date
```

At the same time if the below if your code,

```
def date = new Date()
println date
def date1 = date - 1
println date1
```

it would print like this without the format.

```
Wed Mar 25 09:21:57 GMT 2020
Tue Mar 24 09:21:57 GMT 2020
```

Sample Jenkins declarative pipeline:

```
#! groovy
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            script {
                    def today = new Date()
                    def yesterday = today - 1
                    def daybeforeyesterday = yesterday.previous()
                    println "Today: " + today.format("MM/dd/yyyy") + " && Yesterday: " +
                    yesterday.format("MM/dd/yyyy") + " && The Day before yesterday: " +
                    daybeforeyesterday.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on agent-j2sxm in /home/jenkins/workspace/
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Today: 03/26/2020 && Yesterday: 03/25/2020 && The Day before yesterday: 03/24/2020
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: just to add, you can also use `.previous()` in place of `- 1`. :)

Comment: Hi Vijay, It is not working for me either it is printing the same date or it is throwing error as script are not permitted to use static method ....

Comment: @SubhamKumar It would be better if you could share your pipeline script here.
Check my EDIT.

Comment: @Subham. Given the error, I'd suggest the below. It seems the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin has been installed and enabled, therefore you need to whitelist those methods. Or even using the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Permissive+Script+Security+Plugin plugin in case you would like to grant access to all those internal methods. (Source)[https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/U-94iu3Md0c]

Comment: Hi Vijay, Could you help me with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996636/sending-email-from-jenkins-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment107914253_60996636

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

Edit: Just saw that i was some seconds to late, the solution mentioned above is even better and more elegant.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.*;

node(){
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Instant yesterday = now.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    println(now);
    println(yesterday);
}
```

Comment: It is throwing the error Script not permitted to use java.time.instant.now