# Sending email from jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

Hi I am trying to send email notification from jenkins pipeline but it is not sending any email. 
I am using the below script to send email:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages{
        stage('Test'){
            steps{
                echo 'Ok'
            }
        }
        stage('Email'){
            steps{
                emailext (to: 'abc@xyz.com', replyTo:'abc@xyz.com', subject: "Email report from - '${env.JOB_NAME}'", body: 'test')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The pipeline is being executed but I am not receiving any mail.

Comment: Where you able to send / receive a test email successfully? I think it's under `manage jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail notification` and check box `Test configuration by sending test e-mail` (or something like that).

Comment: Yes, I tested the configuration and it is working from there. I am receiving email

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Please check if you have setup any inbox rules ?

Comment: The pipeline is success but I am not getting any mails.No rules are there in my mail box

Comment: I used try catch and finally block to send a mail.
        finally{
                mail to: 'abx.xyz.com',
                subject: "Backup and upload",
                body: "Backup and upload success "
            }

Comment: Can I customize my email body to produce my data in tabular format and use some color to it.